# Maven2 Binding to a custom Phase

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have a custom plugin that is defined using the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pram.plugintest</groupId>
  <artifactId>pram.plugintest</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>pram.plugintest Maven Mojo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>blah</goalPrefix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      <resources>
          <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
      </resources>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running

```
mvn blah:touch
```

Creates a text file in the target directory as expected. I now create a lifecycles.xml file in the resources directory specified in the pom

```
<lifecycles>
    <lifecycle>
        <id>touch</id>
        <phases>
            <phase>
                <id>package</id>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>touch</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </phase>
        </phases>
    </lifecycle>
</lifecycles>
```

In another maven project, I would like to bind the running of `mvn blah:touch` to an execution task similar to this

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>test1</id>
        <phase>blah:touch</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
<mainClass>mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
...
```

However running this creates the text file but doesn't attempt to run `org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main`

Is this the correct approach?

Ultimately what I would like is to have multiple execution sections in the exec-maven-plugin that are not bound to the default phases. Logically it would look like this

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>test1</id>
        <phase>blah:touch</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
<mainClass>mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
<execution>
        <id>test2</id>
        <phase>blah:touch2</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
<mainClass>mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.SomeOtherClass</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
...
```

So if I run `mvn blah:touch` then `org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main` will be executed and if I run `mvn blah:touch2` then `org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.SomeOtherClass` will be executed instead.

It seems like it should be straightforward to do but there's nothing in the [documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) that seems to point out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the *exec-maven-plugin* for this and you do not need the *lifecycle.xml* if you only would like to execute your plugin during a build.

To execute your plugin during a specific Maven phase, you simply have to add

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>your.artifact.id</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unique-execution-id</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>the.goal.of.your.plugin</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>maven.phase</phase>
                    <configuration>
                     ....
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

Please specify the goal in the **goal** element without the prefix.

Did you read http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html?

Comment: What I would like to achieve is having different execution sections in exec-maven-plugin linked to non default phases. I'll expand on this in the original post